# parsing HTML using DOMDocument

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

I haven't really used DOMDocument up until now, and I guess it suits my needs now, anyway, I have the following code:

```
while ($cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
{
$inputholder .= "<input type='checkbox' name='$cat[cat_name]' value='$cat[cat_id]' />$cat[cat_name]";
}
```

This basically builds a list of checkboxes according to category names and id's.

Now I want to parse out this HTML once it's being processed (eg. when I find out wether to check sevrel of them or not.

so what I know I need to do

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom -> loadHTML($inputholder);
```

Now, I want to check there's a record for a $cat['cat_name'] in my database, if there's, I want to add an attribute`("checked='checked'")` to the correct element (in this case, the one whose name is equal to my query.

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:
So I basically use 3 tables, one is a junction table:
1 table holds parameters, 1 table holds site names and the 3rd table hold both the site_id and the param_id (or cat_id), so for example:

table 1

```
site_id      url
1            http://google.com
2            http://youtube.com
3            http://facebook.com
```

table 2

```
cat_id      cat_name
1           social
2           tubes
3           search
```

and table 3

```
uid    site_id     cat_id 
1         1           3
2         2           1
3         2           2
4         3           1
5         3           3
```

Now the query I use to join those tables is a LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.url, u.url2, ca.cat_id, ca.cat_name FROM urls u
LEFT JOIN cat_urls cu ON cu.url_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN categories ca ON ca.cat_id = cu.cat_id
ORDER BY u.id ASC
```

When it's NULL on cat_id, I know that I can safely print the checkboxes unchecked, but if there's more than 1 category per site I have no way of knowing that, that's why I wanted to run a DOMManipulation.

Hope it clarifies my problem.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing this backward.  Why not determine in your `mysql_query()` if the record exists to begin with? I see no need to return to the db and perform more queries.

Answer (score 0):

Michael is right. You could (and should) do both at the moment you first request your database. It is faster, requires less computing, makes more sense and needs less code.

```
$r = mysql_query("
    SELECT
        cat_id
    ,   cat_name
    ,   IF((cat_id IN (SELECT cat_id FROM cat_urls)), 'checked=''checked''', '') AS cat_checked
    FROM
        categories
");

$inputholder = "";
while ($cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
{
    $inputholder .= "<label><input type='checkbox' name='$cat[cat_name]' value='$cat[cat_id]' $cat[cat_checked] />$cat[cat_name]</label>";
}
```

NB: I also added labels for your checkboxes.

Comment: The problem is that I'm actually dealing with 3 tables, and I have no idea how to build the query.

Comment: Give more details in your question then!

Comment: Okay, I edited my post; the only required change was to change the name of the tables in the query. You could have read the code :-)